# how does the tcp/ip stack get the net_device interface in linux

Tags: networking, network-protocols, linux-device-driver

I was reading through the network device driver code.My driver follows the driver-model.REF:kernel/Documentation/driver-model.
Reading through the interface.txt:
   {
       Device interfaces are the logical interfaces of device classes that correlate
       directly to userspace interfaces, like device nodes.
       Each interface is given a directory in the directory of the device
       class it belongs to.
   }

Havent been able to pinpoint the exact interface yet.So after going through the struct net_device and the Programming interface in the interface.txt file (kernel./Documentation/driver-model)
I again come to the conclusion that its the net_device these people are talking about.
Now what I want to know is the TCP/IP stack the physical and the link layer is the network driver.I want to give the interface my network driver provides to my tcp/ip stack.Question is How ? How can I give the net_device struct to the TCP/ip stack. Does anyone know about this.
Regards
Sraddha

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hierarchy is as follows

struct inet_protosw (internet protocols) has a pointer to a struct member proto (protocol)

struct sock has a pointer to a struct member proto (protocol)

struct sock has member to a struct member sk_buff_head

struct sk_buff_head has two pointer to struct members to sk_buff (one called next, one called prev)

struct sk_buff has a pointer to struct member net_device.

I don't believe you register the net_device with inet_protosw directly.

First  `inet_init` registers the built in network protocols by calling `proto_register`, then it calls `inet_register_protosw` to initialise the protocols, then it initialises the various inet modules (ip,tcp,icmp,etc).

The interface responsible with linking the protocols and the device later has the `register_netdevice` and `unregister_netdevice`, which do what the sound like and register and unregister network devices with kernel. To send a packet from a protocol through a device use `dev_queue_xmit` and `netif_rx` receives a packet passes from the device layer to the network layer, it then calls `netif_rx_schedule` to schedule the packet for further processing.

Resources and documentation on the organisation / workflow include:

- [Anatomy of the Linux Networking Stack](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-networking-stack/)
- [Linux Networking Kernel](http://www.ecsl.cs.sunysb.edu/elibrary/linux/network/LinuxKernel.pdf)
- [The Linux Kernel](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/)
- [Network Data Flow through Kernel](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/images/1/1c/Network_data_flow_through_kernel.png)
- [Kernel Flow](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernelflow)
- [Linux Networking Internals](http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/oreilly/Understanding_Linux_Network_Internals/)
- [Linux Device Drivers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/)
- [How SKBs work](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html)
- [Writing Network Drive Drivers for Linux](http://linuxgazette.net/156/jangir.html)